# Android: How to run google music's "Shuffle all" with shell commands or intents?

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to press "Shuffle all" button in the player's menu with any way if it's even possible.
I know how to emulate keypresses, so it's possible to do this with DPAD emulation (if your device is rooted) via simple shell command `input keyevent`, but this way is very slow and unreliable.
Also I found how to run google music player in PLAYBACK view via intents and start playing, but it's not what I really wanted. In case if someone will be interested, run this shell command:

```
am start -a com.google.android.music.PLAYBACK_VIEWER -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT
```

I couldn't find intents for shuffling in google's music player on my own. Maybe there are other ways to emulate this action or maybe there are intents which I missed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to make a tasker task to start google music on shuffle.

Comment: sadly - no, I didn't..

Answer (score -1):

Right here

I'm Feeling Lucky (32)
    A1: Send Intent [ Action:android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH Cat:Default Mime Type: Data: Extra:String, description: stuff to look for, key: query, id: SEARCH_AND_PLAY Extra: Extra: Package: Class: Target:Activity ]

Comment: Please provide some more explanation on how this answers the question.